# Is there an R function that can remove the rows?

Tags: r

[image]
As you can see, patient ID "3" has NA value on age, sex and race. How do I remove the rows that age=sex=race=NA value. Thank you in advance! I used na.omit but it removed the row if it has even only one NA value.

R function, R code,

Comment: it sounds not working for me.

Comment: Post a reproducible example of what you're trying

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::filter()` with `if_all()`/`if_any()` to check for
conditions in several columns at the same time.

```r
library(tidyverse)  

# Create data that is similar to yours
df1 <- 
  tibble(v1 = 1:10,
         "Patient Age" = sample(c(0:99, NA), 10),
         "Patient Sex" = sample(c("F", "M", NA), 10, TRUE),
         "Patient Race" = sample(c("W", "B", NA), 10, TRUE)) |> 
  add_row(v1 = 11, "Patient Age" = NA, "Patient Sex" =  NA, "Patient Race" =  NA)
df1
#> # A tibble: 11 × 4
#>       v1 `Patient Age` `Patient Sex` `Patient Race`
#>    <dbl>         <int> <chr>         <chr>         
#>  1     1            74 F             <NA>          
#>  2     2            89 F             W             
#>  3     3            39 F             W             
#>  4     4             8 M             W             
#>  5     5            97 M             <NA>          
#>  6     6            20 <NA>          <NA>          
#>  7     7            96 <NA>          <NA>          
#>  8     8            69 F             B             
#>  9     9            58 F             B             
#> 10    10            66 F             B             
#> 11    11            NA <NA>          <NA>

# Drop rows if Age, Sex and Race are NA.
df1 |> 
  filter(!if_all(`Patient Age`:`Patient Race`, is.na))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>       v1 `Patient Age` `Patient Sex` `Patient Race`
#>    <dbl>         <int> <chr>         <chr>         
#>  1     1            74 F             <NA>          
#>  2     2            89 F             W             
#>  3     3            39 F             W             
#>  4     4             8 M             W             
#>  5     5            97 M             <NA>          
#>  6     6            20 <NA>          <NA>          
#>  7     7            96 <NA>          <NA>          
#>  8     8            69 F             B             
#>  9     9            58 F             B             
#> 10    10            66 F             B

# Drop rows if at leat one of Age, Sex and Race is NA.
df1 |> 
  filter(!if_any(`Patient Age`:`Patient Race`, is.na))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>      v1 `Patient Age` `Patient Sex` `Patient Race`
#>   <dbl>         <int> <chr>         <chr>         
#> 1     2            89 F             W             
#> 2     3            39 F             W             
#> 3     4             8 M             W             
#> 4     8            69 F             B             
#> 5     9            58 F             B             
#> 6    10            66 F             B
```